# SQL: Advanced Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying some hours to solve an exercise in a webpage (self-teaching sql) but I can't get the exercise properly.

[This is the summary](http://sql-ex.ru/exercises.php#answer_ref)

And this is the query I have got so far

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(trip_no)
FROM Pass_in_trip AS pit
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.seat as seat, MAX(r.qty) as qty
    FROM (
        SELECT place AS seat, COUNT(trip_no) AS qty
        FROM Pass_in_trip
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT place AS seat
            FROM Pass_in_trip
            GROUP BY place
            HAVING COUNT(ID_psg) > 1
        ) AS s
        ON s.seat = place
        GROUP BY ID_psg, place
    ) as r
    GROUP BY r.seat
    HAVING MAX(r.qty) > 1
) as r
ON place = r.seat
INNER JOIN Passenger AS p
ON p.ID_psg = pit.ID_psg
GROUP BY p.name, p.ID_psg, place, r.qty
HAVING COUNT(trip_no) = r.qty

/* This query gives better results than the previous one, however,
it doesn't pass all tests */

SELECT p.name, COUNT(trip_no)
FROM Pass_in_trip AS pit
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.seat as seat, MAX(r.qty) as qty
    FROM (
        SELECT place AS seat, COUNT(trip_no) AS qty
        FROM Pass_in_trip
        GROUP BY ID_psg, place
    ) as r
    GROUP BY r.seat
    HAVING MAX(r.qty) > 1
) as r
ON place = r.seat
INNER JOIN Passenger AS p
ON p.ID_psg = pit.ID_psg
GROUP BY p.name, r.qty
HAVING COUNT(trip_no) = r.qty
```

Some help would be REALLY appreciated.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(trip_no)
FROM Pass_in_trip AS pit
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT r.seat as seat, MAX(r.qty) as qty
    FROM (
        SELECT place AS seat, COUNT(trip_no) AS qty
        FROM Pass_in_trip
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT place AS seat
            FROM Pass_in_trip
            GROUP BY place
            HAVING COUNT(ID_psg) > 1
        ) AS s
        ON s.seat = place
        GROUP BY ID_psg, place
    ) as r
    GROUP BY r.seat
    HAVING MAX(r.qty) > 1
) as r
ON place = r.seat
INNER JOIN Passenger AS p
ON p.ID_psg = pit.ID_psg
GROUP BY p.name,trip_no
HAVING COUNT(trip_no) = r.qty
```

Comment: I get an error, because r.qty is not included in the GROUP BY clause. I think I'm getting closer but I just can't

Comment: Try again, just modified

Comment: It doesn't work neither, I get the same error. 'r.qty' is being used in HAVING, hence it needs to be included in the GROUP BY clause.